# Install development Jaeger All-In-One into a local Kubernetes cluster via Helm

Tags: jaeger

Jaeger provides [an all-in-one](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes#development-setup) configuration for a development setup of Jaeger that doesn't use tons of memory. [The instructions](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes#development-setup) show how to easily install this via:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/all-in-one/jaeger-all-in-one-template.yml
```

However I manage my development environment using Helm. Is there a Helm chart for this setup that I can use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jaeger helm chart is now available [here](https://github.com/jaegertracing/helm-charts).

You need to add the helm repo first using the following:

```
helm repo add jaegertracing https://jaegertracing.github.io/helm-charts
```

This can be installed with:

```
helm install jaegertracing/jaeger
```